# Автоматическая синхронизация проекта VisualStudio с GitHub

Tags: github, синхронизация

Как настроить синхронизацию проекта VisualStudio с GitHub? А именно как настроить бекап локального проекта на гитхаб. Был неприятный опыт, не хочется снова потерять весь код. В настройках студии нашел систему управления версиями, там подключаемый модуль Git, вошел в своей аккаунт GitHub. После этого на сайте появился моей проект. Но сколько бы раз я после этого его не изменял, на сайте осталась самая первая версия.

Как сделать что б при сохранении проекта он и на сервер отправлялся?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307348/how-do-you-update-a-git-repository-from-visual-studio может помочь

Comment: У меня нет пункта Sync в Team Explorer

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: вам стоит начать с [этого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)